# C# : Error while initializing List object

Tags: c#

I want to know what is wrong here in initializing list object .  can we not create list object in the same class .  What are the set of rules to initialize the list object?

```
class Program
   {

     static void Main(string[] args)
        {

         public int ID { get; set; }
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public int Salary { get; set; }

         List<Program> emloyeelist = new List<Program>();

        emloyeelist.Add(new Program() { ID = 1, Name = "Seema", Salary = 10000 });

     **// error shown for  "employeelist" in employee.Add  stating that "field used like type"** 

        emloyeelist.Add(new Program() { ID = 2, Name = "Arun", Salary = 20000 });
        emloyeelist.Add(new Program() { ID = 3, Name = "Nayana", Salary = 30000 });
        emloyeelist.Add(new Program() { ID = 4, Name = "Nayana", Salary = 12000 });
        emloyeelist.Add(new Program() { ID = 5, Name = "Raman", Salary = 55000 });


    foreach (Program emp in emloyeelist)
        {
            if (emp.Salary > 20000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(emp.Name +" "+"\t"+"has salry"+"\t"+ " " + emp.Salary);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: define properties inside class not inside methods.

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh: got it right.

Comment: Advice: to avoid downvotes, search before you ask.

Answer (score 2):

Move properties outside the method to separate class Employee:

```
class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<Employee> emloyeelist = new List<Employee>();

        emloyeelist.Add(new Employee() { ID = 1, Name = "Seema", Salary = 10000 });
        emloyeelist.Add(new Employee() { ID = 2, Name = "Arun", Salary = 20000 });
        emloyeelist.Add(new Employee() { ID = 3, Name = "Nayana", Salary = 30000 });
        emloyeelist.Add(new Employee() { ID = 4, Name = "Nayana", Salary = 12000 });
        emloyeelist.Add(new Employee() { ID = 5, Name = "Raman", Salary = 55000 });

        foreach (Employee emp in emloyeelist)
        {
            if (emp.Salary > 20000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(emp.Name +" "+"\t"+"has salry"+"\t"+ " " + emp.Salary);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom class, which your `List<T>` can use. Try it like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

After this use your list like this:

```
List<Employee> EmpList = new List<Employee>();

/*Add your data to the list */

foreach (Employee emp in emloyeelist)
{
   if (emp.Salary > 20000)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(emp.Name +" "+"\t"+"has salry"+"\t"+ " " + emp.Salary);
   }
```

}

This way, you wrap your desired data in a custom object, which only has the purpose to contain this data. You do not need to rape the `program` class for it.